# How to load a modal in a partial view ?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm having a problem to load a modal in a partial view,

```
$(".create").click(function () {
            debugger;
            $("#modalTipoPedido").load("ControllerNamePartialView/ActionNamePartialView", function () {
                $("#modalTipoPedido").modal();
            })
        });
```

When I activate this function, in the method load is added the name of the Controller of the view that my partial view is in, then i got a Non Found Error like this:

GET http://localhost:2328/ControllerView/ControllerPartialView/ActionNamePartialView 404 (Not Found)

How to not add the name of the Controller of the view in load method ?

Comment: You can't load a partial from a URL. You can call an action on a controller and get that to return a view but you can't just invoke a partial

Comment: You missing the leading forward slash - `.load("/Contr...`. But always generate your urls correctly using `'@Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName")'`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use a code similar than this:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#mydialog").dialog({
            modal: true,
            width: "800px",
            autoOpen: false
        });

        $(".create").on("click", function () {
            $("#mydialog").dialog("open");
        });

    });
</script>
```

And in your `cshtml` file (your View), you can use something like:

```
<span class="create">
    @Ajax.ActionLink("This is the link",
        "ActionNamePartialView",
        "ControllerNamePartialView",
        new { id = 123 },
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            HttpMethod = "GET",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            UpdateTargetId = "mydialog"
    })
</span>
```

Now, In your `controller` you must have something like:

```
public ActionResult ActionNamePartialView()
{
    var model = //Code to get your model;
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

And in your `Partial View`:

```
@model YourProject.YourModel

<p>All the code that you want to display in your modal</p>
```

Hope works to you